# How do I move my plants vz zombies safegames to android?

Tags: iphone, ios, itunes, jailbreak, android

I want to try strategies here

https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/162404/is-there-a-way-to-transfer-game-progress-from-an-ios-device-to-android

I am now on android. I want to move app data from iphone to android.

The problem is, alas, I already upgraded to iOS 8.3. Ifunbox no longer can do that without jailbreaking.

What should I do?

I can jailbreak (if so, how)

Or, can I just back up everything to iTunes and then copy the back up data to andorid? I rooted my android already.

Comment: What version of iOS are you running? You mention iOS 8.3, but I can't tell if you're saying that you upgraded to 8.3 or if you upgraded *past* 8.3.

Comment: http://adriansieber.com/how-to-extract-data-from-ios-apps-on-mac-os/

Comment: I had ios 8.3 a long time ago. Now it says I need to jail break. I can, if I have to. I hope not

Comment: I have windows computer but not mac

Comment: Try this one maybe? I haven't used it myself, but it looks like it does what you want and looks free. http://www.syncios.com/free-itunes-backup-extractor.html